# file i/o writing and reading file in c

Tags: c, file-io

I am new in c programming.I just start to learn file i/o.So my problem here is after I enter all the data for write file,my program say there is a problem and exited.Which part of my program is wrong？

```
  //THIS PROGRAM WRITE RECORDS IN A TXT.FILE AND THEN READ AND DISPLAY THE RECORDS IN A TXT.FILE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct student
{
    char MatricNo[20];
    int matric[20];
    char CourseNo[20];
    int course[20];
    char Grade[20];
    float Value[20];
 }s[10];

int count=0;

int i,j, no,nu;

int write();
 int read(int i, int j);

int main()
{
int choice;
printf("To record data to txt type <1>\nTo read data from txt type <2>\nTo end the program type <3>\n\n");
    printf("Your Choice: ");
    scanf("%i",&choice);
while(choice!=3)
{


    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
            write();
            break;
        case 2:
            read(i, j);
            break;
        case 3:
            return 0;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    printf("To record data to txt type <1>\nTo read data from txt type <2>\nTo end the program type <3>\n\n");
    printf("Your Choice: ");
    scanf("%i",&choice);
}

fflush(stdin);
getchar();

return 0;
}

// for write data to txt file

int write()
{
    FILE *fw;



   fw=fopen("Register Table.txt","w");



      printf("\nEnter number of student :");
      scanf("%d",&no);

    for(i=0;i<no;i++)
{
    printf("\nEnter student MatricNo :");
    scanf("%s",&s[i].MatricNo);
    printf("\nEnter number of courses :");
    scanf("%d",&nu);
    for(j=0; j < nu; j++)
    {
    printf("\nEnter student CourseNo :");
    scanf("%s",&s[j].CourseNo);
    printf("\nEnter student Grade :");
    scanf("%s",&s[j].Grade);
    printf("\nEnter student value :");
    scanf("%.2f",&s[j].Value);
    fflush(stdin);
fprintf(fw,"%5s %5s %5s %.2f\n",s[i].MatricNo,s[j].CourseNo,s[j].Grade,s[j].Value); 
        fclose(fw); 
   }
   }


   }

int read(int i, int j)
{
FILE *fr;


//read data from txt file
fr=fopen("Register Table.txt","r");

if(!fr){
    printf("not file");
    return 0;
}
else
return 1;

printf("\n\n\t **Register Table  **\n");

    while(fscanf(fr,"%5s %5s %5s %.2f",&s[i].MatricNo,&s[j].CourseNo,&s[j].Grade,&s[j].Value)==1)
    {
            //display data from txt file
printf("\n\n MatricNo\t CourseNo\t Grade\t\t Value");
for(i=0;i<no;i++)
{
    for(j=0; j < nu; j++)
    {
        printf("\n\n %5s %5s %5s %.2f",s[i].MatricNo,s[j].CourseNo,s[j].Grade,s[j].Value);

    }
}

printf("\n\n");
    }

fclose(fr);


}
```

ok,i edited my program and this is it.But now the problem is after i write the file,it could not be read.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <conio.h>

    struct student
    {
        char MatricNo[20];
        int matric[20];
        char CourseNo[20];
        int course[20];
        char Grade[20];
        float Value[20];
    }s[10];

    int count=0;

    int i,j, no,nu;

    int write();
    int read(int no, int nu);
    FILE *fw;
    int main()
    {
        int choice;
        printf("To record data to txt type <1>\nTo read data from txt type <2>\nTo end the program type <3>\n\n");
            printf("Your Choice: ");
            scanf("%i",&choice);
        while(choice!=3)
        {


            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    write();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    read(no, nu);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    return 0;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            printf("To record data to txt type <1>\nTo read data from txt type <2>\nTo end the program type <3>\n\n");
            printf("Your Choice: ");
            scanf("%i", &choice);
        }

        fflush(stdin);
        getchar();
        return 0;

    }

    // for write data to txt file

    int write()
    {




        fw=fopen("Register Table.txt","w");



            printf("\nEnter number of student :");
            scanf("%d", &no);

            for(i=0;i<no;i++)
        {
            printf("\nEnter student MatricNo :");
            scanf("%s", &s[i].MatricNo);
            printf("\nEnter number of course :");
            scanf("%d", &nu);
            for(j=0; j < nu; j++)
            {
            printf("\nEnter student CourseNo :");
            scanf("%s", &s[i].CourseNo[j]);
            printf("\nEnter student Grade :");
            scanf("%s", &s[i].Grade[j]);
            printf("\nEnter student value :");
            scanf("%f", &s[i].Value[j]);



        }


        }


                fprintf(fw,"%s %s %s %.2f\n", s[i].MatricNo, s[i].CourseNo[j], s[i].Grade[j], s[i].Value[j]);   

                fclose(fw);

    }

    int read(int no, int nu)
    {
        FILE *fr;


        //read data from txt file
        fr=fopen("Register Table.txt","r");


        printf("\n\n\t **Register Table  **\n");


                for(i=0;i<no;i++)
                    {
                         for(j=0; j < nu; j++)
                            {
                                fscanf(fr,"%s %s %s %.2f", &s[i].MatricNo, &s[i].CourseNo[j], &s[i].Grade[j], &s[i].Value[j]);
                            }
                    }
                    //display data from txt file
        printf("\n\n MatricNo\t CourseNo\t Grade\t\t Value");



            for(i=0;i<no;i++)
                {
                         for(j=0; j < nu; j++)
                        {

                            printf("%s %s %s %.2f", s[i].MatricNo, s[i].CourseNo[j], s[i].Grade[j], s[i].Value[j]);
                             }
                }




        printf("\n");






        fclose(fr);

    }
```

Comment: Please include the error.

Comment: 0) `s` --> `s[MAX_STUDENT]`... then `s[index].MatricNo`...

Comment: 1)`write` is required to use `no` of the global variables.

Comment: ok,i have edited the code.But now the new problem is I can't read the file when i enter choice "2".It just keep repeating the code that ask me to input the choice.

Comment: You don't need to paste an image to report the compiler output. It's treated as unpolitely to send such hard to read inputs instead of using the tools that are available in *any* environment to get the output as text.

Comment: Your read() function returns always before printf is called. Do you think this makes sense? Indent the code with any autoformatter and paste it again. This would indicate that you know what you've asked.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` <-- Mostly UB. and `case 3:` will never execute. And you need to return an `int` from functions designed to return one

Comment: Sorry for my mistake cause i am new using this web site.I said that I couldn't insert the image due to reputation is because this is what the web site told me.So,I apology for my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-you can not write on file because you close the FILE pointer fw in `write()` function in for loop.

2-You can not read because you exit `read()` function either file is valid or invalid with this code.

```
if(!fr){
    printf("not file");
    return 0;
}
else
return 1;
```

3- your `read()` function can work only if you call it after `write()`. Because code does not know value of `no` and `nu` if you do not call `write()` firstly.

---

I think this code works for you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student
{
    char MatricNo[20];
    int matric[20];
    char CourseNo[20];
    int course[20];
    char Grade[20];
    float Value[20];
}
s[10];

int count=0;
int i,j, no,nu;
int write();
int read(int no, int nu);
FILE *fw;

int main()
{
    int choice;
    printf("To record data to txt type <1>\nTo read data from txt type <2>\nTo end the program type <3>\n\n");
    printf("Your Choice: ");
    scanf("%i",&choice);
    while(choice!=3)
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                write();
                break;
            case 2:
                read(no, nu);
                break;
            case 3:
                return 0;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        printf("To record data to txt type <1>\nTo read data from txt type <2>\nTo end the program type <3>\n\n");
        printf("Your Choice: ");
        scanf("%i", &choice);
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

// for write data to txt file
int write()
{
    fw=fopen("Register Table.txt","w");
    printf("\nEnter number of student :");
    scanf("%d", &no);
    for(i=0;i<no;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter student MatricNo :");
        scanf("%s", &s[i].MatricNo);
        printf("\nEnter number of course :");
        scanf("%d", &nu);
        for(j=0; j < nu; j++)
        {
            printf("\nEnter student CourseNo :");
            scanf("%s", &s[i].CourseNo[j]);
            printf("\nEnter student Grade :");
            scanf("%s", &s[i].Grade[j]);
            printf("\nEnter student value :");
            scanf("%f", &s[i].Value[j]);

            fprintf(fw,"%s %s %s %.2f\n", &s[i].MatricNo, &s[i].CourseNo[j], &s[i].Grade[j], &s[i].Value[j]);
        }
    }

    fclose(fw);
}

int read(int no, int nu)
{
    FILE *fr;
    //read data from txt file
    fr=fopen("Register Table.txt","r");
    printf("\n\n\t **Register Table  **\n");
    for(i=0;i<no;i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j < nu; j++)
        {
            fscanf(fr,"%s %s %s %.2f", &s[i].MatricNo, &s[i].CourseNo[j], &s[i].Grade[j], &s[i].Value[j]);
        }
    }
    //display data from txt file
    printf("\n\n MatricNot CourseNot Gradett Value");
    for(i=0;i<no;i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j < nu; j++)
        {
            printf("\n%s %s %s %.2f", &s[i].MatricNo, &s[i].CourseNo[j], &s[i].Grade[j], &s[i].Value[j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    fclose(fr);
}
```

Comment: Return values are usually 0 for ok and other for error rather than opposite.